# Unable to create iOS App Development certificate

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, developer-program, certificate

I am trying to create a iOS development certificate in the dev center on apple. When I go to create a certificate the "OS App Development" option is greyed out and I am unable to select it. This has noly just  happened, has been fine before. Any one have any clue?

Answer (score 1):

There have been outages to several Apple online services. Sadly, I've seen errors even when the system status is green.

- https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Your best bet is to wait it out if you can. If you cannot, you'll need to open a support ticket to speak with someone that has visibility on the server side. While you're waiting, try safari in private browsing and/or use a different web client to be sure it's not a bad cookie or something browser related.

Comment: Thanks Mike, i'll hold out for as long as possible but have to get a certificate created within the next few days, have opened a ticket with them and they replied with "we see nothing wrong with your account, here are some troubleshooting suggestions".They were not very helpful suggestions.  but if it helps any one else below is their suggestions:

Comment: 1- Make sure that you are using Safari
2- Clean the cache and cookies
3- make sure that you are using the Apple ID related with your account. 
4- Follow the steps mentioned on the guide here below: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW1

Comment: @AstonHaigh Feel free to edit my post and/or make your own answer if you think it will help others. I was thinking you wondered why the site wasn't letting you log in as opposed to you asking procedurally how it's supposed to work when the server side isn't broken due to an internal Apple DNS outage/misconfiguration.